# Is there an embedded key-value store implementation that does not need OS and file system?

Tags: c, nosql, embedded, key-value

In my application running on bare ARM cortex I found I expect a key-value store engine in C. But I don't have a file system neither OS.  I don't have so much data, just a bunch of user config values and running registers for the business.  Is there some open-source project is offering this?

Thanks in advance.
woody

Comment: You wish to store in memory?

Comment: Use `struct`s in a linked list?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are wide range of embedded systems, all with different set of resources (what is your storage device, how much RAM do you have, how fast is your system, ...). We cannot answer the question unless we know what your limits are.

Comment: "Is there some open-source project is offering this?" is not a valid question on SO.  It would be legitimate to ask how you might implement such a system, but without knowing anything about your hardware and the available storage medium, it would be hard to answer.  I have written exactly such a system for parts with flash or EEPROM with power-fail safety and support for integer, string and memory-block values with name keys, back-ground deferred write-back and other features - all these things you might need to specify, but then the question would clearly be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are able to provide a `char` array containing the INI file, [libconfini](https://github.com/madmurphy/libconfini) can be compiled as “bare metal” (see *§ Compiling for Extreme Platforms* [in the manual](https://madmurphy.github.io/libconfini/html/libconfini.html))

Comment: Thanks, It looks worth a trying!